# DateTime::createFromFormat return false converting milliseconds number end with 000

Tags: php, datetime

Hello I have small project restore time from Android java to PHP server.
the time format is milliseconds java (System.currentTimeMillis())

I use DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', millis/1000) to convert milliseconds to date format.

I got strange result that milliseconds end with 000 got false result

here example

```
    $t1 = 1642221885412; // <== SUCCESS
    $t2 = 1642221885000; // <== ERROR
    
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $t1/1000);                
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $txt1 = $dt->format("H:i:s:v");     

    
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $t2/1000);                
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // <== ERROR
    $txt2 = $dt->format("H:i:s:v");     

    print_r($txt1);
    print_r('<br>');
    print_r($txt2);
```

Code above throwing error at second convertion which is time end with 000
Its say

> Call to a member function setTimezone() on bool

If you know what happen please answer my question..

Thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Regards..

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is returning an integer with no period or decimal places since any number ending in `.0` is not needed for a number value (you get an integer value `1642221885` rather than `1642221885.000`). However the `U.u` date format expects a UNIX epoch timestamp followed by a period followed by another number representing milliseconds. When the period and additional numbers are not included, an error is thrown.

You can instead use something like `number_format` or `sprintf` to return a formatted number string (not int or float) so that the returned value is ensured to have a period and milliseconds at the end that the date parser expects, even if they are just zeros.

```php
$t1 = 1642221885412;
$t2 = 1642221885000;

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf("%.3f", $t1/1000));                
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$txt1 = $dt->format("H:i:s:v");     


$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf("%.3f", $t2/1000));
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$txt2 = $dt->format("H:i:s:v");     

print_r($txt1);
print_r('<br>');
print_r($txt2);

// 04:44:45:412<br>04:44:45:000
```